# Loading Qr result to webview url using zxing

Tags: android, webview

Im trying to load Qr result to webview but it show nothing white screen only. is there something did I do wrong?

This is my MainActivity
    package com.project.ciisapp.ciis;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button database;
private Button scan_btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
    database=(Button)findViewById(R.id.database);
    scan_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);


    database.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ReaderActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));

        }
    });



    final Activity activity=this;
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents()==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ReaderActivity.this, scannner.class);
            intent.putExtra("QRurl",resultCode);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
     }


         }
```

This is my webviewQR activity where I sent the result from qr result

```
package com.project.ciisapp.ciis;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;


public class scannner extends AppCompatActivity {
 private WebView wvv;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

wvv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvv);
wvv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
String QRurl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("QRurl");
wvv.loadUrl(QRurl);
WebSettings webSettings = wvv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    if (wvv.canGoBack()){
    wvv.goBack();
    }else {
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
    }
    }
```

webview

```
package com.project.ciisapp.ciis;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    wv.loadUrl("http://peter42398.000webhostapp.com/");
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (wv.canGoBack()){
        wv.goBack();
    }else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
 }
 }
```

the scanner is working  but the button to webview and qr result to webview it makes my app crashes

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: it crashes when click button and sending result from qr to another activity

Comment: please post your crash log

Comment: I fixed by putting files in manifest but the webview page doesnt receive any url from qr scanned

Comment: you're putting an integer (resultCode) in as the QRUrl, not the url into the intent.

Comment: i change my code to  Intent intent = new Intent(this, scannner.class);
                intent.putExtra("QRurl", String.valueOf(result));
                startActivity(intent); the other activity receives it but it has error Unknown URL Scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using intent result as a Url . that's why this error occurred.

> other activity receives it but it has error Unknown URL Scheme

You need to change your `onActivityResult` in `ReaderActivity` like this

```
       IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(result != null) {
                if(result.getContents() == null) {
                    toast = "Cancelled from fragment";
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ReaderActivity.this, scannner.class);
                    intent.putExtra("QRurl",result.getContents());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Comment: bro you saved me so much love ya bud !